# Moving points with scaling grid (points in list)

Tags: c#, winforms, grid, paint, points

I am making some examples for my school work.

Now I am stuck at one point. I will try to include as litllet code as I can but I am not sure what you all need..

(sorry for including names and coments in my native lang)

Heres what I need to do:
I got my "painting program" where you can add points by clicking and then it draws lines to each other. I programed a grid and when you check a checkbox then it looks for closest possible point in rastr(grid)list and then applies its coordinates to the point you're trying to paint with mouse.

You can also scale that grid by trackbar values.

Now here comes my problem: I need to move my painted points with the grid when i'm scaling it. I have no clue since i cant just simply do for each point in grid.X = p.X + trackbarValue. (geting error)

Here is my code for grid and painting:

```
List<Point> rastr = new List<Point>(); //rastr means grid
List<Point> body = new List<Point>(); //painting poits

   private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
   {
            Graphics kp = e.Graphics;
            foreach (Point p in body)
            {
                kp.FillEllipse(st, p.X-s/2, p.Y-s/2, s, s); 
            }
            //double buffer nezapomenout
            if (body.Count>1)
            {
                kp.DrawLines(pero, body.ToArray());//to array prevedeni na pole
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < panel1.Width; x += trackBarGrid.Value)
                for (int y = 0; y < panel1.Height; y += trackBarGrid.Value)
                {
                    if (showGrid == true)
                    {
                        kp.FillEllipse(grid, x-2, y-2, 4, 4);
                    }
                    Point gridpoint = new Point(x,y);
                    rastr.Add(gridpoint);
                }
        }
```

Here is looking for the closest one in grid and then applying coordinates:

```
private void panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (useGrid == true)
        {
            //rozjedu cykly abych nasel nejblizsi bod (porovnavat jednotlivy koordinace)
            foreach (Point p in rastr)
            {
                if (e.Location.X - p.X < trackBarGrid.Value / 2) //kdyz odecteme pozici bodu v listu rastr.x od pozice x kliknuti nesmi byt vetsi nez polovina delky odsazeni rastrovych bodu
                    if (e.Location.Y - p.Y < trackBarGrid.Value / 2) // to same jen s pozici Y
                    {
                        Point zapsat = new Point(p.X, p.Y);
                        body.Add(zapsat); //od tyhle pozice najit nejblizsi point v gridu
                        break;//bod jsme uspesne nasli. Nyni musime cyklus uzavrit aby se nezacli pridavat body ktere nechceme
                    }
            }
            panel1.Refresh();
        }
        else {
            body.Add(e.Location);
            panel1.Refresh();
        }   
    }
```

Also my trackbar event:

```
    private void trackBarGrid_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rastr.Clear();
        panel1.Refresh();
    }
```

And my poor attempt on this

```
    private void trackBarGrid_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Point p in rastr)
        {
            p.X += TrackBarValue;
            p.Y += TrackBarValue;
        }
        panel1.Refresh();
    }
```

One last note that I don't need to keep that "freehand" painting. I can just use that grid one.

Here are some pictures..

[Before scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hErbO.jpg)

[After scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpImt.jpg)

Comment: Please help im desperate :D

Comment: 1) Please edit your question to proper English; this is a professional archive. 2) To scale the coordiantes of your points you need to multiply, not add to them. You must know the scaling factor (or factors, if you scale diffently in x and y direction.) Then you can get the new Points by multiplying the old values with the scaling factor(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can chose to scale your graphics. One is extremely simple the other somewhat involved.

Here is the simple one:

Simply add this to the top of the `Paint` event:

```
float scale = trackBar1.Value / 100f;
if (scale == 0) scale = 1;
e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);
```

This looks a bit convoluted but the `TrackBar` will not have a value when the `Paint` event is called at first.

The `Graphics` object itself is now scaled and **everything you draw** with will be scaled.

That was really simple.

One possible issue you may have is that everything, including the width of a `Pen` will be scaled up or down.

You were going for the more involved way in your question, so let's do that as well..:

First we create a function that scales a point accoding to the `TrackBar`'s `Value`. Here it is:

```
PointF scaledPoint(PointF pt, float scale, bool unscale)
{
    if (unscale) return new PointF(pt.X / scale, pt.Y / scale);
    else return new PointF( pt.X * scale, (pt.Y * scale));
}
```

Two things are worth noting:

- The function actually works with `PointF` not `Point`. This is really important as the scaling must not lose **precision**! Going from, say 5 down to 33% and back up again will not go back to 5 but to 3..!
- There is an extra parameter that will remove the scaling from a point. We don't need it at the moment; but you will, once you want to catch a point from a `MouseClick` when the scaling is on!

Now let's use it to scale our point list.

We could do it directly, maybe like this:

```
for (int p = 0; p < body.Count; p++)
     body[p] = scaledPoint(body[p], scale, false);
```

While this will work is has a **nasty** issue: When we move the `TrackBar` it will **reapetedly** apply a **growing** scaling factor. This means that the graphics will get larger **faster and faster**..not good.

Instead we create a second `List<PointF> bodyO` with the original point values, which need to maintain..

That means we add points to `bodyO` but draw with `body` and scale `bodyO` to body..:

```
void scalePoints(float scale)
{
    for (int p = 0; p < body.Count; p++)
        body[p] = scaledPoint(body0[p], scale, false);
}
```

We call pretty much as in your code:

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    scalePoints(trackBar1.Value / 100f);
    panel1.Refresh();
}
```

Let's see how this works in the `Paint` event:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    float scale = trackBar1.Value / 100f;
    if (scale == 0) scale = 1;

    bool showGrid = true;  // inserted for testing

    // these graphics work with the scaled points:
    foreach (PointF pt in body) e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, 
                                  pt.X - 2, pt.Y - 2, scale * 4, scale * 4);
    if (body.Count > 1) e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Black, body.ToArray());

    // here we don't use points but calculate the coordinates, so we need to scale
    for (int x = 0; x < panel1.Width; x += trackBar2.Value)
        for (int y = 0; y < panel1.Height; y += trackBar2.Value)
        {
            if (showGrid == true)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Gray, 
                           scale * (x - 2), scale * (y - 2), scale * 4, scale * 4);
            }
            // Point gridpoint = new Point(x, y); // not sure what you do here..?
            // rastr.Add(gridpoint);   // maybe add the point scaled?
        }
}
```

Note that I scaled the size of the points as well.  Btw, to make both version look all the same you would have to scale the `Pen` as well:

```
using (Pen pen = new Pen(somecolor, penWidth * scale))
```

Finally here is how to add a new Point in the MouseClick:

```
private void panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    body0.Add(scaledPoint(e.Location, trackBar1.Value / 100f, true));
    body.Add(e.Location);
    panel1.Invalidate();
}
```

We add it to the original list `bodyO` reversing the current scaling and as is, i.e with the current 'pixel size' to the scaled list..

[image][image]

Btw: The many grid points take some time without `DoubleBuffering`; this creates some flicker.. So either use a `Panel` **subclass** with `DoubleBuffering`:

```
class DrawPanel : Panel
{ 
   public DrawPanel()
    { DoubleBuffered = true; }
}
```

Or go for a `Picturebox` (recommended)!

Comment: WOW man :D Didn't see that coming. I feel like it's not my work anymore xD Thank you very much! Appreciate it! Will type as soon as possible if i made it work.

Comment: Damn getting pretty tired and lost there :D This is the first error it got me
http://picpaste.com/awdawdawd-BKzQmZVG.JPG

Comment: Hehe, no need to copy it all, just study it ;-) - Note that I didn't quite get the grid thing until I edited the question. So there is quite some work left for you..

Comment: You didn't keep the two lists in synch. Include this `body = body0.ToList();` right after setting up the first points! (I didn't mention this, sorry..) Tired? Sleep ;-)

Comment: Yeah okey :D let's see if i can finish it by tomorrow. Thanks much. Btw that grid list was supposed to draw the grid but I guess it was just badly done :D And i already double buffered that panel in the properties :) Will try that picture box tho :) thx for help!

Comment: Yeah I'd sleep but kinda would like to present it tomorrow becouse of the bonus points :D

Comment: Oh, well, best of luck then. You can't DoubleBuffer a Panel in the properties, though; it has to be subclassed. PictureBox comes with DoubelBuffering out of the box and can also add two bitmap layers below any graphics you draw on it..

Comment: Okey then :D not sure what I have done there then :D oh i only double buffered the form

Answer (score 0):

I somehow managed to get those points outa that list then edit them and put them back in. So as you said i just have to figure out those scaling factors. It is already moving but not coresponding to the grid. I said im sorry for my english so as u see there is no possibility for me to correct it even more :D sorry ... Im out u aint helping me ;( (just laughed a bit about that profesional archive note) 
Some ppl post here even worse questions than this :D anyway thx again kinda solved it myself.
Just that multiplying thing :)

```
 private void trackBarGrid_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (trackBarGrid.Value > trackbarval)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < body.Count; i++)
                {
                    Point point = body[i];
                    point.X += trackBarGrid.Value - trackbarval;
                    point.Y += trackBarGrid.Value - trackbarval;
                    body[i] = point;
                }
            }
            else if (trackBarGrid.Value < trackbarval)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < body.Count; i++)
                {
                    Point point = body[i];
                    point.X -= trackbarval- trackBarGrid.Value;
                    point.Y -= trackbarval- trackBarGrid.Value ;
                    body[i] = point;
                }
            }
            rastr.Clear();
            panel1.Refresh();
            trackbarval = trackBarGrid.Value;
        }
```

Comment: Well, I didn't ask for perfection, just a little more effort. The word is not 'u' it is 'you' , not 'outa' but 'out of' etc.. And telling you this a big help because it will improve your chances of getting good answers and reduce the danger of downvotes.. - Glad you made progress. I don't see you doing any multiplication, though..? If you want I'll post a working answer..

Comment: Hint-1 The trackbar can only hold integers, so they should be interpreted as percentages, i.e. the scaling factor would be trackBar.Value /100f. Hint-2: You really should use PointF instead of Point because you will quickly lose precision. Hint-3: For good results keep a List with the original points __and__ one with the scaled points; then always calculate form the original and always draw the scaled list.. Otherwise scaling up and down will not get yopu back to the original..

Comment: Okey :) Thank you for answer then :) I will try to type properly.

Comment: Also that help with keeping original one is good I will stick with that. I posted my code without multipliying so it is just a small change. If you have some spare time I can post my whole code and u can have a look on it I am realy lost with this and I am considering giving up :D

Comment: Unfortunately I still couldn't figure out how to include multiplying. I am not experienced programer and this seems kind of hard for me :D

Comment: See my answer. It should help you, one way or the other ;-) - I didn't quite understand what the grid list does, so I left it out..